# Cakephp Auth always generates same hash at login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a simple application running on cakephp 2.4

I have set everything I need for the Auth Component, but I can't do a login.
It hashes a password when it is creating one user, but at the login, the hash is always the same regardless the user input password.

To be sure of it, I checked this, which outputs always the same value:

```
debug(AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']));
```

But if I go:

```
var_dump($this->data['Administrator']['password']);
```

It shows the correct password given.

Why that is happening? What is the more probably possibility?

(Yes, I din't use 'Users' as usual, but I configured it correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core works more than likely you can verify this by running the unit tests for the AuthComponent. I'm sure the `password()` method is tested as well.

I guess your alias is not "Administrator" because something else is wrong in your code. Guess it's your auth component configuration. So debug the alias and see if its "Administrator".

And why do you debug `$this->data['Administrator']['password']` when the suspected code reads `$this->data[$this->alias]['password']`?